# exporting a jar file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, export

I did the following things in the exact order:

Create java project named Testing.

Created a class with the package com.(myname).util named Calculator.java with a basic adding method.

Created another project named JarTest.

Created a Class called JarUse where I used something from Calculator.

I then used export jar file on Testing project to create a jar which has Calculator class in it.

In the JarTest project, I went to "Java Build Path" and added that said jar file which I named Testinlib.

Inside Jar Use class I tried to use the functions from Calculator by importing it with: import com.(myname).util.Calculator;

Problem: "The import com.(myname).util" cannot be resolved"

I did this all just to test whether it would work, I swear to god I watched a youtube video and did the same as the uploader only with different names, and it worked for him but not for me.

Can somebody help me please ? I actually want to start another Project, but I can't use/create my own jar files because of the error mentioned above. Even this simple example I basically copied from youtube won't work -_-

Comment: Maybe you added the JAR to the Java build path of a run configuration instead of to the Java build path of the project. Could you please show a screenshot of _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_?

Comment: It's always worth double checking that the contents of the exported jar (Testinlib) actually contains the artifacts you think it should have. You should be able to open the jar file with any archive utility.